# Header is showing some strange gap that i can't fix - CSS

Tags: html, css

I am having some issues with my CSS. My header is showing a top margin of around 25px. This issue is visible Chrome, Opera and other browsers (but is not visible in Firefox). I have tried editing the floating, setting `margin-top:0px` and other possible fixes but nothing is working.

I can use `margin-top:-25px` but while this fixes the problem for other browsers, it messes up Firefox.

I have also checked my CSS thoroughly but can't figure out why that gap is there.

The link to the website is [Here](http://symbolwdd.com/completed/abhayayks/cn/contact.php)

Comment: You will probably want to create a jsfiddle with the relevant code rather than link people to a full website to figure it all out themselves.

Comment: I quote, `This issue is view-able in browsers other than firefox i.e chrome, opera etc` . So which browser are we talking about?

Comment: we are talking about browsers other than firefox...
Lets take Chrome as an example...kindly open the link in chrome

Comment: @anurupr I think, there's a comma missing and he wants to say `This issue is view-able in browsers other than firefox, i.e chrome, opera etc` So we are talking about `chrome, opera, etc`

Comment: @user2982923 try to reproduce the issue in a fiddle using jsfiddle for example. And probably when you'll be able to reproduce the issue you'll find your fix at the same moment.

Comment: This is the problem...The place where the inverted commas are showing up, i am including the header via php include function.
<?php include("includes/menu.php"); ?>. Firefox is ignoring it but other browsers are not...can you guide me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove one "." after

```
<!-- page-head -->
.
```

this comment to resolve this issue
﻿﻿

Comment: Thank youuuuuuuuuuuuuu.....
This fixed it...Can you please lead me why the comments was making this issue?

Comment: That's not because the comments, there are a space/line before the header. A line has a height, so...

Comment: Actually "." was create problem not comment and "." is a character and in your css default line-height define "line-height: 1.4" so it take this space.

Comment: Yeah...thats right...and this issue was driving me crazy :-(

Comment: This is the problem...The place where the inverted commas are showing up, i am including the header via php include function.
<?php include("includes/menu.php"); ?>. Firefox is ignoring it but other browsers are not...can you guide me?

Comment: <?php include("includes/menu.php"); ?>

This is it...when i remove this tag, the commas don't show up...when i add it, the commas appear...

Comment: what is written in "menu.php"?

Comment: <header id="header" class="header">
  <p id="logo" class="logo"><a href="index.php"><img src="../images/logos/logo.png"/></a></p>
  <nav id="navigation" class="navigation">
    <ul>
      <li><a style="font-size:20px;font-weight:bold;" href="index.php">我们</a></li>
      <li><a style="font-size:20px;font-weight:bold;" href="work.php">作品</a></li>
      <li><a style="font-size:20px;font-weight:bold;" href="contact.php">联系 </a></li>
      <li><a style="font-size:20px;font-weight:bold;" href="start.php">项目计划 </a></li>
   <li><a href="../index.php">ENGLISH </a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49460/discussion-between-user2982923-and-dheeraj)

Answer (score 0):

Its the user-agent stylesheet in webkit based browsers like `chrome , opera`

Set the following css rules to your `ul`

```
 -webkit-margin-before: 0;
 -webkit-margin-after: 0;
 -webkit-padding-start: 0;
```

Then you won't have a problem in `firefox`